# SQL request to sum across a column with sign function of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trades;
CREATE TABLE trades( 
    id      integer,
    type    text,
    price   double ,
    cpty    text,
    notional double);

INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'BUY',96.28,"CPTY1",20000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'BUY',97.28,"CPTY2",20000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'SELL',99.28,"CPTY1",100000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'SELL',98.28,"CPTY3",400000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'SELL',95.28,"CPTY3",600000);
```

I would like to sum the notional but the notional should be multiplied by:

- 1 if the trade is a buy
- -1 if the trade if a sell

Basically the result should be:

```
20000+20000-100000-400000-600000 = -1060000
```

Comment: Would you please update your question and add a tag for the specific flavor of SQL you're using.  Thanks.

Comment: `select sum(case when [type] = 'BUY' then 1 when [type] = 'SELL' then -1 else 0 end * price) from trades`

Comment: The initial setup seems to indicate MySQL, but this is can be a fairly generic SQL question/solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a MySQL question, but the query uses pretty standard SQL and should work for other DBMSes.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4793b5/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trades;
CREATE TABLE trades( 
    id      integer,
    type    text,
    price   double ,
    cpty    text,
    notional double);

INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'BUY',96.28,"CPTY1",20000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'BUY',97.28,"CPTY2",20000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'SELL',99.28,"CPTY1",100000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'SELL',98.28,"CPTY3",400000);
INSERT INTO trades VALUES (1,'SELL',95.28,"CPTY3",600000);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT cpty
  , SUM(
      CASE 
        WHEN type = 'BUY' THEN notional
        WHEN type = 'SELL' THEN - notional
        ELSE 0
        END
    )  AS notionalTotal
FROM trades
GROUP BY cpty
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4793b5/1/0)**:

```
|  cpty | notionalTotal |
|-------|---------------|
| CPTY1 |        -80000 |
| CPTY2 |         20000 |
| CPTY3 |      -1000000 |
```

EDIT: I initially had a subquery, and then summed over that, but in this instance, it's not necessary. I've simplified.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following ( I presumed your `DB` as `MySQL` ):

```
SELECT sum(case when type = 'SELL' then -notional 
                when type = 'BUY'  then  notional 
            end) sum_notional
  FROM trades;

 sum_notional
 ------------
   -1060000
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6937f1/7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (written for MS SQL; may work for other flavours of SQL too):

```
select sum
(
    case 
        when [type] = 'BUY' then 1 
        when [type] = 'SELL' then -1 
        else 0 
    end 
    * price
) 
from trades
```

The case statement converts the BUY/SELL to 1/-1 for each row (I've also said 0 for where it's neither in case that's a possibility).*

The result of the case statement is then multiplied by the price to give that row's value.

All of the above is encapsulated in a `sum`, so we get the result for all rows.

*As an additional point; if you can only have 'BUY' or 'SELL' you may want to replace your `[type]` column of type `text` with an `TypeIsBuy` column of  `bit`; so the database is restricted to a `true`/`false` value, and you use the least amount of space needed to hold the information.